# Session doesn't persist in flask-session

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I have a reactJS web application as my frontend and I am making a request to route '/addData' in my Flask server and setting a state variable called 'FileName'.

```
session['fileName'] = 'smthing'
```

Then immidiatly after this line, I printed the session variable as:

```
print(session['fileName'])
```

and it printed the proper name that was assigned.

Then I called another route '/visualize' in the flask server. When I try to access the session variable inside this route using:

```
print(session.get('fileName', 'not set'))
```

it prints 'not set'.

**Note: I am using Flask-session (server side session)**

shown below is my **init**.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_session import Session
import os

socketio = SocketIO()
db = SQLAlchemy()
sess = Session()

def create_app(debug=False):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.debug = debug
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret'
    app.config['USE_PERMANENT_SESSION'] = True
    # app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(25)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql://root:pass@localhost/tensormap"
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    from .resources import main
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    socketio.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    sess.init_app(app)
    CORS(app, expose_headers='Authorization', support_credentials=True)
    return app
```

Shown below are my 2 routes:

```
from flask import jsonify, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session
from . import main
from .. import db
from .database_models.data_preproc import dataset
import os
import json

@main.route('/addData', methods=['POST'])
def addData():

    file = request.files['file']
    datasetFile = file.filename

    dirPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '.', 'dataset'))
    path = '{}{}{}'.format(dirPath, "/", datasetFile)

    splitFileInfo = datasetFile.split(".")
    fileName = splitFileInfo[0]
    fileFormat = splitFileInfo[1]

    if dataset.query.filter_by(fileName=fileName).one_or_none():

        print("**********************************")
        session['fileName'] = splitFileInfo[0]
        print(session.get('fileName', 'not set'))
        return "error"


    else:

        file.save(path)   

        session['fileName'] = splitFileInfo[0]
        print(session['fileName'])

        # writing the file entry in the database.
        data = dataset(fileName, path, fileFormat)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()   
        print("**********************************")

        return "file uploaded successfully"

@main.route('/visualizeData', methods=['GET'])
def visualizeData():
    print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
    print(session.get('fileName', 'not set'))
    entry = dataset.query.filter_by(fileName='store').one()
    print(entry.filePath)
    if entry:
        with open(entry.filePath, 'r') as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            default = ""
            data = default.join(data)
            return data
    else:
        return 'None'
```

I tried alot of things in StackOverflow but nothing worked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set session.modified flag to  True?

Comment: I did not try this. But without it the session should persist right

Comment: @Suleka_28 did you ever get this problem fixed?  I have the same problem with flask sessions even if expliciting setting session.modified = True.  I've experienced this problem using filesystem as well as redis backends for the server side session.